# How to apply a function into every element

Tags: matlab, matrix

If I have vector `[1,2,3,4]`,I hope to use a function `f` into every element to get

```
[f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4)]
```

If I have a matrix `mat`

```
>> mat=magic(3)
mat =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

I hope to get

```
     f(8)     f(1)     f(6)
     f(3)     f(5)     f(7)
     f(4)     f(9)     f(2)
```

Is any simple method to do this in matlab?

Comment: Have you tried `f(mat)`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to contain the function you're trying to use this on, in a [mcve]. Most functions can be restructured to accept matrices.

Comment: @Adriaan Sorry,I just test a undefine function `f`，but not a specify function.I realize that is impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Use MATLAB's [arrayfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) function as follows:

```
arrayfun(f,mat)
```

**Example**

```
mat = magic(3); %defines input
f = @(x) x.^2; %defines f (f is the square function)
arrayfun(f,mat); %applies f on mat
```

**Results**

```
mat =

 8     1     6
 3     5     7
 4     9     2

arrayfun(f,mat)=

64     1    36
 9    25    49
16    81     4
```

Comment: @SardarUsama - regarding to first comment, that's true, I fixed it. regarding to the second one - it's only for demonstration

Comment: This is a general solution indeed. Just be aware that most function can be modified to have implicit matrix support (like the element wise power you already employ; I get that that's just an example) and that those methods will probably be faster, as `arrayfun` is just a loop in disguise

Comment: just for the lazy, like me: [vectorize](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vectorize.html?s_tid=doc_ta)